# Inline vertical diagrams

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-cd, xy-pic

Is there a package that allows for vertical in-line diagrams, like the one below?

[image]

I've tried the following code inline using xy-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip,2cell]{xy}
\begin{document}
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. $\xymatrixrowsep{.1mm}\xymatrix{\mathcal{E} \ar[dd] \\ \ \ \ F \\ \mathcal{B}}$ This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. 
\end{document}
```

with the following result

[image]

but I was hoping for a method that didn't disturb the line-height placement of the next line down, like in the example above.

Comment: Could you post a *complete* small  code of what you've tried.

Comment: @Bernard I don't understand what you're asking for; the above code will compile in any latex document with the xypic package loaded in the preamble.  Are you asking me to copy-paste in my preamble as well? It's 65 lines long, so I figured that would just distract from the point of the post. Apologies if I'm missing something simple, I use latex to write math documents but I'm not familiar with standard coding procedures etc.

Comment: Can't you extract a minimal code with the relevant packages, reproducing your problem? Much more people will want to help if they can compile instantly to understand what happens.

Comment: @Bernard Is the above edit what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `\raisebox{<up/down shift>}{content to shift}`

For example

```
 bla bla bla \raisebox{0pt}{$\begin{matrix}\mathcal{E}\\\downarrow\\\mathcal{B}\end{matrix}$} bla bla
```

will produce

[image]

Here how `\raisebox{}` works:

```
 in the middle of the text....
 \raisebox{0pt}{
 $\begin{matrix}
 \mathcal{E}\\\downarrow\\\mathcal{B}\end{matrix}$
 }
 at the top of the text...
 \raisebox{10pt}{
 $\begin{matrix}\mathcal{E}\\\downarrow\\\mathcal{B}\end{matrix}$
 }
 at the bottom of the text....
 \raisebox{-10pt}{
 $\begin{matrix}\mathcal{E}\\\downarrow\\\mathcal{B}\end{matrix}$
 }
```

[image]

**Upgrade for labeled arrows**

Using a two column matrix is it easy (maybe not so pretty) to label the vertical line. Eg

```
 $
 \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
 \begin{matrix}
 \mathcal{E}&\\
 \downarrow&F \\
 \mathcal{B}&
 \end{matrix}$
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I propose this variant approach, using only the `stackengine` package and basic latex commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.\setstackgap{L}{2.2ex}$\Vectorstack{\mathcal{E}\\ \phantom{\scriptstyle F\!}\downarrow {\!\scriptstyle F} \\ \mathcal{B}}$ This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here there are two approaches:

1. The first is to use the common commands of `amsmath` and `amssymb`.

---

```
$\overset{\mathbb{E}}{\underset{\mathbb{B}}{\scriptstyle \downarrow}} \scriptscriptstyle F$
```

---

2. To use `xy` package which contains (`xy-pic`).

---

You here can see the different approaches in the screenshot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
Et sem luctus quisque porta viverra hymenaeos consequat et ridiculus commodo platea mollis sem erat quam sollicitudin, luctus arcu lacus vestibulum nam Pharetra purus ullamcorper nam cursus sollicitudin nec risus $\xymatrix@C=.2pt{
\mathcal{E} \ar[d]^F& \\
\mathcal{B} &
}\hspace{-.25cm}$ lipsum $\overset{\mathcal{E}}{\underset{\mathcal{B}}{\scriptstyle \downarrow}}$. Sit volutpat etiam. Dapibus. Dictumst quisque. Suspendisse pulvinar dignissim. Natoque volutpat dui sodales viverra volutpat lacus $\overset{\mathbb{E}}{\underset{\mathbb{B}}{\scriptstyle \downarrow}} \scriptscriptstyle F$. Fusce pede proin rutrum enim. Velit, diam taciti. Praesent hymenaeos consequat, libero cum accumsan.
\end{document}
```

[image]